# Simple regression proof using general formula

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, proof

I want to derive the least square estimation of the coefficients for $y=\beta_0+\beta_1*x_1+\varepsilon$ using the general formula.

Can someone walk me through how to get from B to D in the image below?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/9zwvO.jpg]

Comment: What do you mean by "the general formula"? These lectures notes might be helpful: http://socserv.socsci.mcmaster.ca/jfox/Courses/soc740/lecture-3-notes.pdf

Answer (score 1):

There is a lot of information missing going from B to D.

The form of the model in B is used to show the matrix form of the model with X and X$^T$X defined in step C.

Then let β = (β$_0$', β$_1$)$^T$

In matrix form you can write

Y=β'X + ε  where ε=(ε$_1$, ε$_2$,...,ε$_n$)$^T$.  Then to minimize ε$^T$ ε take partial derivative of ε$^T$ ε with respect to β$_0$' and β$_1$. This gives in matrix form

β^ =(X$^T$ X)$^T$ Y  where β^ is the least squares estimate for β.

After matrix multiplication you will see that β^ is the vector with components β$_0$^ and
β$_1$^ equal to what is shown in B and D but with the estimates for  β$_0$ and β$_1$ used in the equation for β$_0$' replacing β$_0$ and β$_1$ respectively.